# How to use function move_uploaded_file in php

Tags: php

This code in "upload.php"

```
<?php
    session_start();
        $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $pic = $_FILES['pic']["name"];
        $folder = "../images/users/";
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']["tmp_name"], "$folder".$pic); 

        $mysqli = connectDB();
        upload($id,$pic,$mysqli);
    ?>
```

Function upload

```
function upload($id,$pic,$mysqli)
    {
        $pic = $mysqli->real_escape_string($pic);

        $sql = "UPDATE users SET pic = '$pic' WHERE id = '$id'";
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
    }
```

and this code in html

```
<form name="submit" action="include/upload.php" method="post">
    <input type="file" value="Choose file" accept="image/*" id="pic" name="pic">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>
```

It's not working. Image not move folder and image path not insert in database.

Comment: Put `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the beginning of the script, to ensure that you see any errors or warnings from functions like `move_uploaded_file`.

Comment: you never bothered checking if the upload succeeded. just because you get some information in $_FILES doesn't mean everything worked. There's a `['error']` parameter in there for a reason. that's the **FIRST** thing you should check, before doing anything else. and you're also simply assuming the query succeeded. you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['pic']["tmp_name"], "$folder".$pic);
```

You can just do:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"], $folder.$pic); // Note the single / double quotes
```

But even easier:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $pic = $_FILES["pic"]["name"];
    $folder = "../images/users/";
    $path = $folder.$pic; // New variable

    if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pic"]["tmp_name"], $path) ) {
        $mysqli = connectDB();
        if( upload($id, $path, $mysqli) ) {
           echo 'File uploaded';
        } else {
          echo 'Something went wrong uploading file';
        }
    } else {
       echo 'Something went wrong uploading file';
    }
```

So the function becomes:

```
function upload($id, $path, $mysqli)
    {
        $path = $mysqli->real_escape_string($path);

        $sql = "UPDATE `users` SET `pic` = '$pic' WHERE `id` = $id";
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);

        return $result; // returns true or false
    }
```

Adding backticks around table and column names prevents an error called mysql reserved words. Because the `$id` is an integer (in most cases). You shouldn't quote it. This is because you make a string from an integer which is something you don't want to do as integers are faster and saver to use.

To make html clear you want to upload a file you need to add something to your form. So the form becomes:

```
<form name="submit" action="include/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" value="Choose file" accept="image/*" id="pic" name="pic">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Adding double quotes around `$folder` shouldn't make a difference. Variables are expanded inside double quotes, but no inside single quotes.

Comment: MYSQL automatically converts strings to integers when storing into an `INT` column. So that shouldn't cause the query to fail.

Comment: The only important thing in your answer is the `enctype` change. But you have a typo, it should be `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: @Barmar I know this but it's not required and to make it more general troughout the whole code I think it's the cleanest to make it all equal.

Answer (score 0):

form tag should be in the format :

```
< form name="submit" action="include/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

(add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form tag, this will solve your problem.)

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. Keep in mind that this question holds an accepted answer that is five years old - adding a new answer is fine, but it should also add new insights